# Redirects 301 with URL parameters not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I created an url redirect (http 301) with

```
redirect /product/?utm_source /product-new/
```

But this is not working the url parameter is ignored in the redirect doesn't redirect as expected. Are url parameters not working with redirects?

Answer (score 0):

I *assume* that you only want to redirect those requests if that specific query parameter is present? Your question is not clear in that ...

If so, then have a try using the more flexible rewriting module instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^utm_source$
RewriteRule ^/?product/?$ /product-new/ [R,L]
```

Above variant will preserve the query string for the redirection. If you want to drop it you need to add the `QSD` flag to the two existing flags `R` and `L`.

The details are documented: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html